# Trouble displaying constraint values - SICStus clpfd

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

I am trying to solve a problem for a class that consists of this:

> Fill the white cells on the each barrels side with different digits from 1 to 6. Digits cannot
>   repeat in every horizontal and vertical directions. Each number on the barrels top must
>   be equal to the sum or product of the four different digits in the barrel. All top numbers
>   are different and less than 91.

I can achieve the results fine, but I need to display the barrel's results and when I run my base case it shows this:

```
[_24087,18,60,17,_24343,72,_24471,_24535,14]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,1,2,2,5,1,3,6,4,4,6,2,5,3,1,5,1,6,2,4,3,6,3,4,1,2,5]
Result achieved in 0.015 sec.
Resumptions: 6197
Entailments: 1306
Prunings: 3520
Backtracks: 62
Constraints created: 107
```

The 1st list is the barrels and the 2nd list the Matrix calculated with labeling.

In order to calculate the barrels I use this on a rule:

```
getlist(Matrix,CounterX,CounterY,InnerSize,Value), % gets the barrel sublist
all_distinct(Value),
sum(Value, #=, SSet),              % sum
prod(Value, VSet),                 % product
Set #= SSet #\/ Set #= VSet,       % chooses one
Set #=< MaxValue,
insertinto(Set, List, NewList),    % inserts into the barrel list
```

Since SICStus doesn't have a product calculation rule, I created this one:

```
prod([H|T], R) :-
    prod(T, H, R).

prod([], R, R).
prod([H|T], V, R) :-
    NV #= H * V,
    prod(T, NV, R).
```

I don't understand where the problem actually lies.

- In my prod rule -> It seems to unify correctly but seems not to when 1 is in the sublist.
- How I unify the sum or prod -> Maybe that barrel can be a sum or prod and can't unify with *Set* correctly.

Comment: "I don't understand where the problem actually lies." Hard to help you. Make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell what you expect and what you get.

Comment: (I don't understand the specific SICStus/clpfd problem at hand, but got curious about the puzzle and wrote a MiniZinc model of it: http://hakank.org/minizinc/barrels.mzn . It contains reference to the source of the puzzle.)